# why my keras model is not getting right results

Tags: tensorflow, keras

Just started building my first model using `TensorFlow` and `Keras`. Model gets evaluated to 98% accuracy but I'm stuck while predicting the model.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
from keras.preprocessing import image

mnist = tf.keras.datasets.mnist

(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()

tf.keras.backend.image_data_format()== 'channels_last'


x_train, x_test = x_train / 255.0, x_test / 255.0

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
  tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
  tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax')
])

print(x_train.shape)

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])


model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=5)

model.evaluate(x_test,  y_test, verbose=2)

img = Image.open('8.png')
img = img.resize((28,28)
im2arr = np.array(img)
im2arr = im2arr.reshape(1,28,28,1)
print(im2arr.shape)
prediction = model.predict_classes(im2arr)
print(prediction)
```

Comment: Please provide any output and error messages you get from the code execution.

Comment: Sure. So basically the code doesn't throw any error..It runs but the result it gives is wrong. When I give 8 as the input, the output turns out to be [7] and when 1 is the input image, it predicts as [3]. Please be patient and help me with the code. Thank you

Comment: Probably you just have to divide the input image by 255, like you did for `x_train` and `x_test`.

Comment: Tried doing that..it doesn't seem to work :(..output is still the same

Comment: Also increase epochs to something like 100 or 1000. What training and validation accuracies are you getting?

Comment: Increased the epochs, still doesn't work. The output is: loss: 0.1458 - accuracy: 0.9554 - val_loss: 0.1492 - val_accuracy: 0.9548
And the model still doesn't give the right results.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what's inside your `8.png`, but I changed a few things in your code and for me it worked with a few test images.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import PIL
from PIL import Image
from keras.preprocessing import image


mnist = tf.keras.datasets.mnist

(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()

tf.keras.backend.image_data_format()== 'channels_last'


x_train, x_test = x_train / 255.0, x_test / 255.0

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
  tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
  tf.keras.layers.GaussianNoise(0.05),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(32, activation='relu'),
  tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax')
])

print(x_train.shape)

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])


model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=10)

model.evaluate(x_test,  y_test, verbose=2)

img = Image.open('8.png').convert('L')
img = img.resize((28, 28), resample=PIL.Image.BILINEAR)
im2arr = 255. - np.array(img, dtype=np.float32)
im2arr = im2arr / 255.
im2arr = im2arr.reshape(1,28,28,1)
print(im2arr.shape)
prediction = model.predict_classes(im2arr)
print(prediction)
```

Basically I just modified the model to be a little more robust to overfitting and added some preparation to the input image before feeding it to the model.